# How to read Mifare classic Nfc tag?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

Could anyone explain the procedure of reading the NFC tag. I have gone through this link.   http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html And Nfc Demo link also. There are two different procedures to read the tag. Do i need to go into blocks and sectors level to read my Mifare classic 1k tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unless you are using Ndef. If you are storing Ndef data on your tag, you can connect to it as a Ndef type tag, and then just pass Ndef messages back and forth, the phone will handle all the block and sector reads for you. But if you are storing data that is not Ndef, then you have to read and write individual blocks.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write data in Mifare Classic Tag without using sectors and blocks?